# I am getting "Cannot resolve method 'snapToRoads()' " error for the following code...how to fix it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-roads-api

I am trying to use Google Roads api, in which want to call a method `snapToRoads`, but I am facing an issue.

I tried to use other method of `snapToRoads`, but it also shows same error

```
LatLng[] page = latLngs
            .subList(lowerBound, upperBound)
            .toArray(new LatLng[upperBound - lowerBound]);
SnappedPoint[] points = RoadsApi.snapToRoads(context, true, page).await();
```

RoadsApi.snapToRoads(context, true, page)

shows... **"Cannot resolve method snapToRoads(..,...,...)'"**

I believe i have added the necessary dependencies in app level gradle :

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.9.3'    
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
```

If there is any other dependency which i have not added then please let me know.

Import statements have also been added in my Activity:

```
import com.google.maps.GeoApiContext;
import com.google.maps.RoadsApi;
import com.google.maps.model.SnappedPoint;
```

Link which i have referred to: [roads-api-samples](https://github.com/googlemaps/roads-api-samples)

Comment: what is `context` in your code?

Comment: @GhostCat I meant i am trying to use RoadsAPi in which i have that method call...

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko GeoApiContext is the context

Comment: Are you using it from an activity or a fragment

Comment: @trinadhthatakula I have used an Activity

Comment: is the import `import com.google.maps.RoadsApi;` red or underlined at all?

Comment: @Blundell Nothing of that sort at the top of the class where the imports are written....but the red underline is at this line : **snapToRoads(context, true, page)**

Comment: right, so that might mean you are using the wrong parameters for the method then. What happens when you delete the method parameters and press `cmd + p` to show the paramater docs?

Comment: Please note: it is less important to use **bold** formatting for textual explanations. It is way more important that you format code as code (by indenting with 4 spaces, or by marking and clicking that {} button above the edit window).

Comment: You could also try to downgrade your dependency versions to be the same as the example code: https://github.com/googlemaps/roads-api-samples/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L25-L28

Comment: @Blundell yes i will try that

Comment: @Blundell There are two types of method for the same : 1) snapToRoads(GeoApiContext context, LatLng... path)...2) snapToRoads(
      GeoApiContext context, boolean interpolate, LatLng... path) ..... and i am using the 2nd type

Comment: @Blundell downgrading the dependency didn't worked

Comment: ah ha! @PrasadKawalekar try this: `RoadsApi.snapToRoads(((GeoApiContext) context), true, page)`

Comment: @Blundell It didn't worked ! :(

Comment: is it still "cannot resolve" or diff error? What is your import for `LatLng` maybe you are using the wrong one?